# Program won't run because variables "may be uninitialized"?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, compiler-errors

I'm trying to make a new thread for parsing xml from an rss feed. When I click run it says there are errors please correct them etc. I have 2 classes in my project. The other class has no errors and this class below has only warnings that a lot of the things in the try/catch statements may be uninitialized. I understand that and figured I should still be able to run the program anyways, I expect them to be initialized and if they're not that's fine I want to know about it. Is this really what's going on or am I missing something? I thought it would compile if something may be uninitialized but its not certainly uninitialized.

```
public class RssParse extends Thread  {
    Thread th=new Thread() {
            public void run(){
              System.out.println("1");
              URL iotd;
            try {
                iotd = new URL("http://www.nasa.gov/rss/image_of_the_day.rss");
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("2");
            BufferedReader in;

                try {
                    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iotd.openStream()));
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

            System.out.println("3");
            XmlPullParserFactory factory;
            try {
                factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
            System.out.println("4");
            XmlPullParser xpp;
            try {
                xpp = factory.newPullParser();
            } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("5");
            try {
                xpp.setInput(in);
            } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("6");

            int eventType;
            try {
                eventType = xpp.getEventType();
            } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println(eventType+"!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
            while(eventType!=XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT){
                if(eventType==XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT){
                    System.out.println("start");
                }
            }

            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            }//method
        };//thread

}//class
```

Comment: try using the "Clear all lint markers" option

Comment: @robertboloc OP says there are errors please correct them...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at this try/catch block for example :

```
    URL iotd;
    try {
        iotd = new URL("http://www.nasa.gov/rss/image_of_the_day.rss");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

If `iotd = new URL("...")` fails, `iotd` will remain uninitialized.

There are two ways to deal with this :

- Assign a default value to `iotd`, like : `URL iotd = null;` However, it's bad here because if you use `iotd` later its value may be null and can throw a NullPointerException.
- Stop the execution of your function if something failed instead of just printing the stack trace. For example you can add a `return` statement in the `catch` block :

  ```
  URL iotd;
  try {
      iotd = new URL("http://www.nasa.gov/rss/image_of_the_day.rss");
  } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      return;
  }
  ```

Comment: Ok thanks, I was under the impression it would compile still if something "may be uninitialized".

Answer (score 2):

All the warnings you are getting are because all your `catch` blocks are not dealing with the exception at all (just printing the stacktrace to standard out).

Let's see it through an example:

```
URL iotd;
try {
   iotd = new URL("http://www.nasa.gov/rss/image_of_the_day.rss");
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

at that snipped you are declaring a `iotd` variable as a URL but without initializing it (not assigning any value), you do it inside the `try` block - which isn't wrong by the way. However if for any reason the statement inside the `try` block throws an exception program flow will go to the `catch` block leaving the `iotd` variable with its initial value (unassigned).

So, in that case, execution of the program will continue and when reaching this statement:

```
in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iotd.openStream()));
```

it will find no value assigned to the `iotd` variable.

To remove the warning regarding the uninitialized value you can either assign a `null` value to the variable when declaring it or rethrow another exception inside the `catch` block, stopping the program flow.

In the other hand, the snippet you posted here is not just one class, it's actually two as you are extending the `Thread` class and then creating an anonymous one inside its body. Using threads is easier than that in Java, just implement the `Runnable` interface and then instantiate a new thread from that interface:

```
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

and then:

```
new Thread(new MyRunnable()).start();
```

cheers

Answer (score 0):

you need to initialize the variables above the `try catch` block, or give them a value in `catch` or `finally` block

find updated code here

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory;

public class RssParse extends Thread  {
    Thread th=new Thread() {
            public void run(){
              System.out.println("1");
              URL iotd=null;
            try {
                iotd = new URL("http://www.nasa.gov/rss/image_of_the_day.rss");
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("2");
            BufferedReader in=null;

                try {
                    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iotd.openStream()));
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

            System.out.println("3");
            XmlPullParserFactory factory=null;
            try {
                factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
            System.out.println("4");
            XmlPullParser xpp=null;
            try {
                xpp = factory.newPullParser();
            } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("5");
            try {
                xpp.setInput(in);
            } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("6");

            int eventType=-1; // set to a default value of your choice
            try {
                eventType = xpp.getEventType();
            } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println(eventType+"!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
            while(eventType!=XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT){
                if(eventType==XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT){
                    System.out.println("start");
                }
            }

            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            }//method
        };//thread

}//class
```